how to combine multiple value + text in 1 cell?
i have this raw data that my boss required me to transform it into a calendar view

on the separate sheet (same google sheet file) we have this calendar view thats already filled with all the hotels we have affiliated with, date selector, and also time. The idea behind creating this tool is to enable users to easily see how many photo sessions are scheduled for a particular day, the hotels where these sessions will take place, and other relevant information such as the client's name, room number, photographer, and client's email.
To achieve this, we need create a calendar Google Sheets that dynamically updates and displays the required information based on the selected date and hotel.

i have tried to ask chat gpt about this, but i always got errors when i copy the formula to my google sheet.
Here is the link to the google sheet file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16shZQnV3C9lwdI9SYezduxrvWKqQ5jN_8Q2MuHA5iWY/edit?usp=sharing
we would appreciate any help or advice!!

chatgpt was not trained on google sheets formulae - pointless to ask, as it will hallucinate 99% of times

use in B4:
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B3:3&A1+A4:A200, {Input!E:E&Input!A:A+Input!B:B, 
 "Client: "      &Input!D:D&CHAR(10)&
 "Room No.: "    &Input!F:F&CHAR(10)&
 "Photographer: "&Input!C:C},  2, )))



MY MAN, YOU'RE MY SAVIOR!! THOUSANDS OF THANK YOU TO YOU MY FRIEND
